# Unable to install python imposm.parser

Tags: python, imposm

I am trying to install imposm.parser (http://imposm.org/docs/imposm.parser/latest/) on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4. I have a virtualenv activated.

- I successfully installed the following: **python-dev**, **protobuf-compiler** and **libprotobuf-dev**

When I try `pip install imposm.parser` I get the following error:

```
Collecting imposm.parser
Downloading imposm.parser-1.0.7.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 20, in <module

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-l_5r7vwz/imposm.parser
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my own answer in case someone comes across this with the same problem.

Padraic is right - it only runs with Python 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7. However, there is a port for Python 3 here: https://github.com/tpievila/imposm-parser.

**I am currently not aware of a port for imposm. This is just imposm.parser!**

Steps to install (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev
$ pip install git+git://github.com/tpievila/imposm-parser.git
```

**Note:** `python-dev` refers to Python 2.7 on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation. You also need to install `python3-dev` if you don't have it already.

Answer (score 4):

`imposm.parser` does not work with python3

> Imposm runs with Python 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7 and is tested on Linux and Mac OS X.